# What do I put in this config.js file for cartographer angular app?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

https://github.com/tylergreen/cartographer

It says to add my "firebase url" to the ./app/js/config.js file but no explanation of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file named `config.js` inside your `app\js` directory.
2. Add something like the following to it:

   `module.exports = function(config) {
     config.set({ FBURL: 'https://chovy.firebaseio.com/' });
   };`
3. Reload the application in your browser

Comment: With that change the 404 error on `config.js` goes away. But I still can't get the cartographer project to run. It seems like the project "lacks some polish" and you might be better off simple starting with angular-seed.

Comment: the maintainer has not responded to my issues. I'm guessing this project is a dead end.